# Django admin ascii error

Tags: python, django, admin

I know what the problem is that I have a special char. But this is the tricky part: It's already in the Django db so when I want to delete it in the Admin I get the error page so I can't delete it.

models

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Richtingen(models.Model):
    naam = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    omschrijving = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.naam, self.omschrijving)
class Leraren(models.Model):
    naam = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    voornaam = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'leerkrachten', default='leerkrachten/anoniem.png')
    email = models.EmailField()
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.naam, self.voornaam, self.foto, self.email)

class Klassen(models.Model):
    naam = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    numeriekeCode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    richting = models.ForeignKey(Richtingen, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leraar = models.ForeignKey(Leraren, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.naam, self.numeriekeCode, self.richting, self.leraar)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s' % (self.naam, self.numeriekeCode, self.richting, self.leraar)

class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    telefoonNr = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    adres = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bericht = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.email, self.telefoonNr, self.adres, self.bericht)
```

admin

[image]
error

[image]

Comment: Can we see the model?

Comment: Please specify your question. At least show that special char and an error message. We cant help you without any hint... :(

Comment: there is nothing in model Klassen and it gives me an error when I click on the button add. I searched what was wrong and in my model Richtingen I have an item that has some special chars in it so I can't delete that one to remove the error. And that is why I can't add anything to model Klassen because it has a foreign key of model Richtingen.

Comment: Special chars by themselves shouldn't cause problems.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, If I want to add a new item in richtingen and the string is "it's complicated". It will give me an error because of the char: '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I just noticed you have from future import unicode_literals: all the literals you have are unicode and the `u` in front of some of them is superfluous):

Your `__str__` methods return Unicode strings; but you are in Python 2, and that function is supposed to return a bytestring. Django will try to use its return and decode it into a unicode string, but that fails if there is non-ASCII data in there. Just call those `__str__` functions `__unicode__`.

As long as you are on Python 2 only; otherwise, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods).

Comment: the problem is that I already have it in my db and I want to get rid off it but it won't let me.